# There is a workaround for the Angular Material 2 Select multiple?

Tags: angular, select, html-select, angular-material2

I been trying to adapt or create a similar select type from angular material for angular2, any ideas to base on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a hint is this link : http://4dev.tech/2016/06/adding-the-multiselect-feature-to-an-angular2-autocomplete/

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't need a workaround anymore. You can add `multiple` to the select:

```
<md-select placeholder="State" multiple>
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{ state }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Then it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am surprised why this is not in documentation!!

Comment: The `multiple` attribute is listed in the [API documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) but I had to search it, too.